SQLite does not generate compound key correctly
I have a peculiar problem with EFCores SQLite framework, which works fine for PostgreSQL. So there is this entity:
[PrimaryKey(nameof(InterviewProcessId), nameof(Position))]
public record StageEntity
{
    public InterviewProcessEntity InterviewProcess { get; set; } = null!;
    public Guid InterviewProcessId { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}

Which is referenced like this:
[PrimaryKey(nameof(StageInterviewProcessId), nameof(StagePosition), nameof(TalentUserId))]
public record TalentStageEntity
{
    public StageEntity Stage { get; set; } = null!;
    public Guid StageInterviewProcessId { get; set; }
    public int StagePosition { get; set; }
    public Guid TalentUserId { get; set; }
}

// model builder
modelBuilder.Entity<TalentStageEntity>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.StageInterviewProcessId, e.StagePosition, e.TalentUserId });
    entity.HasOne(e => e.Stage)
        .WithMany(e => e.TalentStages)
        .HasForeignKey(e =>  new { e.StageInterviewProcessId, e.StagePosition });
});

Npqsql will create a correct database schema from that. SQLite however, pulls an ID for StageEntity out of thin air. Here is a comparison (marked yellow):

SQLite then proceeds to throw this error:

SQLite Error 1: 'foreign key mismatch - "ef_temp_TalentStages" referencing "Stages"'.

I am not really sure what to do differently. I've tried making the relatioship bidirectional by adding IList<TalentStageEntity> TalentStages  and this to the model builder:
modelBuilder.Entity<StageEntity>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.InterviewProcessId, e.Position });
    entity.HasOne(e => e.InterviewProcess)
        .WithMany(e => e.Stages)
        .HasForeignKey(e =>  e.InterviewProcessId);
});

I tried defining everything with attributes and everything with model builder and everything with both. Now I'm out of ideas.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

Is the database created from scratch in SQLite, or are there already tables with relations? Have there been migrations yet?

@AlexanderPetrov The auto-generated migration for these changes is what throws the error.

I suppose you need to specify the names of the keys that were before that. .HasKey(...).HasName("..."). Or delete all migrations and start from scratch if you can.
